# How can I split an image in several layers of same size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I want to split this image

[image: to split in layers]

in several layers, one for each square.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Select the first square
- Open the action window (alt +f9)
- Record a new action (bind it to f2 for example)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on the new layer thumb to select it.
- Press <kbd>→</kbd> until it is aligned above the next square.
- Single left click to select the first layer.
- Stop recording of the action.

You can bind the action to a key and press it repeatedly for each row. After you finish a row select the first square on the next and run the action again.

Now all the squares are seperate layers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is.  Select -> Copy -> Paste.  Repeat for each square...

Comment: Is there a way to setup a macro or something to do it?

Comment: You could r ecord an `Action` to do the copy-paste-deselect part. You'd still have to manually select the squares.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the image as the only layer.  Duplicate layer many times - one for each square.  (Original layer could count as one, but you may prefer to keep it handy, just in case.)  Use the eraser tool on each layer to erase all but one square.  Be careful to keep track of which square you want to keep.

This involves no effort aligning, unlike single-square copy/paste techniques.

Perhaps Photoshop has a way to trim the size of layer if it has huge margins of pure transparent around a small area. If so, that would help reduce memory usage and file size.